# How to make Landscape Architecture design sketch like this?

Tags: landscaping

I went to the Melbourne School of Design on OpenDay, I found theses beautiful Landscape Architecture design pictures. But I do not know how to create these pictures. Such as using what softwares, etc.

If anyone have some ideas, I look forward to hearing from you.

Best regards,

Jane

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, looks nice but in my opinion a bit too mechanical and set.  Learning how to hand draw landscape design SELLS far better than any software stuff...just sayin'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about graphic design, not gardening.

Comment: In addition to it being about graphic design, it's seeking an off-site web resource, which has been ruled off-topic. See [this meta post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/634/do-we-really-want-questions-asking-for-off-site-resources) for more information.

Comment: This question is currently in the review queue to be considered for re-opening. I'm voting to keep it closed for the reasons above, and because the OP hasn't been here since they posted it. Therefore, even if there was a way to edit it to be on-topic, the OP wouldn't be available to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the 3D imagery has been done in SketchUp, and then the pages have been composed in InDesign (adding the images and text, headings etc). There are plenty of online tutorials for beginners in this software, particularly on YouTube, but it is probably best to enroll in a class at a local Tafe or tertiary institution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with Viv. The photos you've taken look like they combine some basic 3D imagery before using something like [Adobe's InDesign](http://www.adobe.com/au/products/indesign.html) to prettify it.

Here are a few software packages I've heard of that are great for architecture and landscaping and garden design

- Chief Architect
- My Garden Planner
- Plan a Garden
- Sketch Up
- Realtime
- Landscaping Plus